# Converting Managed solution to unmanaged

Tags: powerapps, power-virtual-agents

I have created a ChatBot through Power Virtual Agent. I have exported solution as managed solution. I have imported solution into a Power Apps. Now I need to make some changes in chatbot and it shows it is a managed solution so can't edit it. I have gone through the way Microsoft mentioned to click on Allow customization but that option is disabled.

This flow Power Virtual Agents Flow Template metadata or parameters has changed. Refresh the node.
Diagnostic Trace Id: Trace id not available. Headers: {"cache-control":"no-cache, no-store","content-type":"application/json","x-cci-botdesignerserver-buildid":"2023.11.1.3452","x-ms-activity-vector":"00.00.00.00","x-ms-correlation-id":"1e86a323-d1c3-4856-918e-e34093a3e2d3","x-ms-islandgateway":"GA0000003","x-ms-service-request-id":"46617678-997b-4935-ad1b-aa57594d16b6"}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make changes after importing manage solution. you should go back to your environment export again as unmanaged solution along with all customization option true and then import again.

Comment: Thank you. I followed steps you mentioned. Now managed error is not popping up but still I get below error while I make change. This flow Power Virtual Agents Flow Template metadata or parameters has changed. Refresh the node. Diagnostic Trace Id: Trace id not available. Headers: {"cache-control":"no-cache, no-store","content-type":"application/json","x-cci-botdesignerserver-buildid":"2023.11.1.3452","x-ms-activity-vector":"00.00.00.00","x-ms-correlation-id":"1e86a323-d1c3-4856-918e-e34093a3e2d3","x-ms-islandgateway":"GA0000003","x-ms-service-request-id":"46617678-997b-4935-ad1b-aa57594d16b6"}

Comment: Is this because of I created Virtual agent with basic (free) license and now I have premium license?

Comment: have you included all the required tables and flows to your solution before exporting ???